# How to derive conditional expectation E[X|Y=y] if X and Y follow bivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

I am struggling to derive $E[X|Y=y]=\mu_X+\sigma_X\rho(\frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma_Y})$ when X and Y follow bivariate normal distribution.

I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531865/conditional-expectation-of-a-bivariate-normal-distribution), but I don't get how to get the following steps:

$$
\frac{\int x \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}-\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)^2 \right)dx }{\int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}-\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)^2 \right) dx} = \frac{\int (x+\mu_X+\sigma_X\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}) \exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(\frac{x}{\sigma_X})^2 )dx }{\int exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(\frac{x}{\sigma_X})^2 ) dx}
$$

$$
E[X|Y=y] = \int x \frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}dx 
$$

Substitute the formula in and get:
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} &= \frac{1}{\sigma_X\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}exp\left( -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} (\frac{x- (\mu_X+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_Y}\rho(y-\mu_Y))}{\sigma_X})^2
\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: Did you try to ask the commenter directly?

Comment: Try my hint I gave to this [other OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4560629/949989) of one of the most popular MSE questions.

Comment: @ManateePink, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment there.

Comment: That last result $\rho\sigma y$ cannot be correct because it doesn't depend on $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ as it should. Did you follow my advice in my previous commet?

Comment: @KurtG. I think I get the $(x-cy-d)^2$, but I am not sure how to get rid of $exp(1-\rho^2)$.

Comment: It seems you think that $\exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(...)^2)$ equals
$$
\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(...)^2)}{\exp(1-\rho^2)}\quad ?
$$
If this is the case it is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: Your formulas look still wrong. I added an answer that explains why there should appear a term $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ in the standard deviation of the conditional distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Approach 1***

With two independent standard normals $\varepsilon_X,\varepsilon_Y\,,$ the correlated normals $X,Y$ can be written as
\begin{align}
X&=\mu_X+\sigma_X\Big(\rho\varepsilon_Y+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\varepsilon_X\Big)\,,\\
Y&=\mu_Y+\sigma_Y\varepsilon_Y\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
X=\mu_X+\sigma_X\Big(\rho\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\varepsilon_X\Big)\,.
$$
This implies
$$
\boxed{\quad\mathbb E\big[X\big|Y=y\big]=\mu_X+\sigma_X\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\,.\quad}
$$

***Approach 2***

The covariance matrix of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$
\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_X^2 &\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho\\\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho&\sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has inverse
$$
\Sigma^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_Y^2 &-\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho\\-\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho&\sigma_X^2\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The joint density of $X,Y$ is then
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\\
&\quad\times\exp\Big(-\frac{\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2-2\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2}{2\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)}\Big)\,.
\end{align}
From (looking at the denominator of the term in the exponential)
\begin{align}
&\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2-2\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2\\[2mm]
&=\sigma_Y^2\Big(x-\mu_X-\sigma_X\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\Big)^2+\sigma_X^2(1-\rho^2)(y-\mu_Y)^2
\end{align}
and the unconditional distribution of $Y$,
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_Y}\exp\Big(-\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{2\sigma_Y^2}\Big),
$$
it follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_X\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{(x-\mu_X-\sigma_X\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y})^2}{2\sigma_X^2(1-\rho^2)}\Big)\,.
\end{align}
This means that, conditional on $Y$, the random variable $X$ is normal with

- standard deviation $\sigma_X\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,,$ and
- mean $\mu_X+\sigma_X\rho\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\,,$ as expected.

Comment: Can I understand the last formula as the conditional density function which has the formula of normal density function with some mean and some standard deviation, and thus it tells me directly the conditional expectation equals to this mean?

Comment: Of course. Whatever constant you subtract in $\exp(-\frac{(x-...)^2}{2...})$ from $x$ is the mean.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work it out again and edit my post.