# Conditional expectations and weighted sums

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Z$ denote random variables; and define $Y$ as their weighted average, i.e. = $Y = \lambda X + (1 - \lambda)Z$ for some $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. Assume that $X$ and $Z$ are independently drawn from the *same* smooth distribution, with mean $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$. We are interested in the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|Y = y]$.

In the extreme case that $\lambda = 0$, $Y$ and $X$ are unrelated so $\mathbb{E}[X|Y = y] = \mathbb{E}[X] = 0$.

In the other extreme case that $\lambda = 1$, we have $Y = X$ so $\mathbb{E}[X|Y = y] = y$.

Given this, it is natural to conjecture that $|\mathbb{E}[X|Y = y]|$ is strictly increasing in $\lambda$. (Indeed, one may think that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y = y] = \lambda y$.) Is this true in general? If not, what are minimal assumptions on the distribution required to make this true?

Comment: Looks wrong. What I believe is:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X|Y]&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbb E\Big[Y-(1-\lambda)Z\,\Big|Y\Big]=\frac{Y}{\lambda}-\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}\mathbb E[Z|Y]\,.
\end{align}

Comment: @KurtG. The main question is whether the absolute value of the conditional expectation is strictly increasing in $\lambda$. I think this should be true?

Comment: @KurtG.: Since X and Z have the same distribution, that would imply that $\mathbf E[X|Y]=\mathbf E[Z|Y]$ and thus $\mathbf E[X|Y]=Y$.

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle Unless $\lambda = 1/2$, I think that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] \neq \mathbb{E}[Z|Y]$? Learning the value of $Y$ could tell us more about the value about $X$, or more about the value of $Z$.

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle. This seems wrong. When $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution they don't have to be identical. If it were true that $\mathbf E[X|Y]=\mathbf E[Z|Y]$ holds we could use $Y=X$ to get $X=\mathbf E[Z|X]=0$ (by independence of $X,Z$) and $Y=Z$ to get $Z=E[X|Z]=0\,.$ Thus $X=0=Z\,.$

Comment: Right, that's an additional assumption. I ran into this trap before. Sorry!

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle NP. I find this post quite interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture
$$
\mathbb E[X|Y=y]=\lambda y
$$
is not true in general.

***Example.***

When $X,Z$ are i.i.d and $N(0,1)$ then $Y$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$
with
$$\tag{1}\sigma^2=\lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2\,.$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ have correlation $$\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\sigma}$$ their [joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2) is
$$\tag{2}
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{\sigma^2x^2-2\sigma\rho xy+y^2}{2\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}\Big)\,.
$$
According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4581316/949989)
$$\tag{3}\boxed{\quad
\mathbb E[X|Y=y]=\rho\frac{y}{\sigma}=\frac{\lambda y}{\sigma^2}=\frac{\lambda y}{\lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2}\,.\quad}
$$
The function $\lambda\mapsto\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2}$ is not
monotone. It has a maximum of approx. $1.21$ around $\lambda=0.70\,:$

[image]

***Remark.***

When $X,Y$ are i.i.d. and $N(0,1)$ and we change $Y$ slightly to
$$\tag{4}
Y'=\lambda X+\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}Z
$$
then it is easy to see that $Y'$ is $N(0,1)$ and has correlation $\lambda$ with $X\,.$ Like before it follows now that the conjectured relationship
$$
\mathbb E[X|Y'=y']=\lambda y'
$$
holds because $\sigma^2$ is now one.

Comment: Thanks for this! Although this wasn't the original question, I wonder if the monotonicity holds more generally if we hold the distribution of $Y$ fixed when we vary $\lambda$? This seems like a natural generalisation of holding the variance of $Y$ fixed in the normal distribution case.

Comment: @afreelunch Your questions are inspiring but I'd like to see you trying to answer them yourself. Tips: take as examples all the simple enough distributions where you can calculate it all: uniforms, exponentials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

More an idea than an answer, but too long for a comment:

Assume that the random $X,Z$ are i.i.d. drawn from a distribution that has probability density $q(x)$.

Let $p(x,y)$ be the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.
We have $$p(x|y) = \frac{p(x,y)} {p_y(y)} = \frac{p(y|x) q(x)} {p_y(y)}$$

Given $X=x$, we have that $Y = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) Z$, thus conditional on $X = x$, we have formally
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y = y| X = x] = \mathbb{P} [ Z = \frac{y-\lambda x}{1-\lambda}],$$
using independence.

Thus, we get for the conditional density

$$p(y|x) = \frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda}\right).$$

Analagously, we have for the conditional density on $Z$
$$p(y |z) = \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}q\left(\frac{y -(1-\lambda)z}{\lambda}\right).$$

Then we get for the conditional expectation

$$\mathbb{E}[X| Y=y] = \int x p(x\vert y) dx = \int x \frac{p(y|x) q(x)} {p_y(y)} dx = \int x \frac{\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda}\right) q(x)} {p_y(y)} dx  = 
\frac{\int x \frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda}\right) q(x) dx} {\int \frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda} \right) q(x) dx} = \frac{\int x q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda}\right) q(x) dx} {\int q\left(  \frac{y -\lambda x}{1-\lambda} \right) q(x) dx}.
$$

This is now an expression that you could differentiate with respect to $\lambda$, which might yield some insight on the monotonicity (I did not do the calculations, so I don't know if this helps in the end).